# Transações com PHP

Tags: php, back-end

Rapaziada, estou tendo um problema com Transações com PHP. A transação só armazena a segunda parte do código, a primeira tabela fica mostrando que está vazio, levando em conta que o algoritmo executa tudo e não ocorre nenhum erro. 
Abaixo o código.

```
<?php
    require "conexao01.php";

    function filtrarDados($dado) {
        $dado = trim($dado);
        $dado = stripslashes($dado);
        $dado = htmlspecialchars($dado);

        return $dado;
    }



    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        $connecting = conectaAoMySql();

        $msg = "";

        $especialdade = $medico = $data = $horario = $nome = $telefone = "";

        $especialdade = filtrarDados($_POST["especialidades"]);
        $medico = filtrarDados($_POST["medico"]);
        $data = ($_POST["dataConsu"]);
        $horario = ($_POST["horaConsult"]);
        $nome = filtrarDados($_POST["UnomePaciente"]);
        $telefone = filtrarDados($_POST["uTelPaciente"]);

        try {    

            $connecting->begin_transaction();

            if (! $connecting->query("insert into Paciente (Id, Nome, Telefone) VALUES (null, '$nome', '$telefone')"))   
             throw new Exception ('Erro ao inserir dados');

             if (! $connecting->query("insert into Agenda (Especialidade, Medico, DataConsulta, Horario, codId) VALUES ('$especialdade', '$medico', $data, '$horario', LAST_INSERT_ID())"))
             throw new Exception ('Erro ao inserir dados');

             $connecting->commit();
             echo "Executado com Sucesso!";
        }
        catch (Expection $e) {
                $connecting->rollback();

                echo "Ocorreu um erro na transação: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

alguém poderia dar um help?

Comment: O auto commit está desabilitado? `$connecting->autocommit(FALSE);`

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam está igual o código acima.